# UITableViewCell not work when clicked without UIButton

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, target

I am working tableviewcell when clicked. It will not working when I clicked the cell, I don't want use UIButton because of height messed up. Here my code

```
cell.accessibilityIdentifier = "\(indexPath.section)"
cell.tag = indexPath.row
cell.target(forAction: #selector(reminderClicked), withSender: self)
```

and

```
@objc func reminderClicked(_ sender: UITableViewCell) {
   print("\(sender.tag) - \(String(describing: Int(sender.accessibilityIdentifier ?? "0")))")
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: tableview has a method func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a TableViewDelegate function that you can use to check for clicks on the cell.

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}`

Comment: Not working, can you explained what should I put something in that? I did simply "print(indedPath.row)" and it does nothing

Comment: Never mind, I realized I have tableview.allowsSelection = false, I should change to true. Now it working, thank you.